# bash script not functioning when run by cron

Tags: python, bash, cron

the below bash script is set to kill firefox processes (used by python script) and kill any running same script before running the python script in a loop untill it give error code 0.

```
#!/bin/bash

for pid in $(pidof -x start-manheim.sh);
do
    if [ $pid != $$ ]; then
        kill -9 $pid;
    fi
done

while true
do
    #pkill -f firefox;
    echo "starting script on `date`";
    python3 mmr-gen.py;
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
        break;
    fi
done
```

The script run manually perfectly as it is supposed to, but when using cron :

```
*/2 * * * * /bin/bash /root/start-manheim.sh >> /root/manheim.log
```

the script just loops through it without running any python.
log data:

```
starting script on Sat Jul  9 14:54:01 UTC 2022
starting script on Sat Jul  9 14:54:02 UTC 2022
starting script on Sat Jul  9 14:54:03 UTC 2022
starting script on Sat Jul  9 14:54:04 UTC 2022
starting script on Sat Jul  9 14:54:05 UTC 2022
starting script on Sat Jul  9 14:54:06 UTC 2022
starting script on Sat Jul  9 14:54:08 UTC 2022
starting script on Sat Jul  9 14:54:09 UTC 2022
starting script on Sat Jul  9 14:54:10 UTC 2022
starting script on Sat Jul  9 14:54:11 UTC 2022
starting script on Sat Jul  9 14:54:12 UTC 2022
starting script on Sat Jul  9 14:54:13 UTC 2022
starting script on Sat Jul  9 14:54:14 UTC 2022
starting script on Sat Jul  9 14:54:15 UTC 2022
starting script on Sat Jul  9 14:54:17 UTC 2022
starting script on Sat Jul  9 14:54:18 UTC 2022
starting script on Sat Jul  9 14:54:19 UTC 2022
starting script on Sat Jul  9 14:54:20 UTC 2022
starting script on Sat Jul  9 14:54:21 UTC 2022
starting script on Sat Jul  9 14:54:22 UTC 2022
starting script on Sat Jul  9 14:54:23 UTC 2022
starting script on Sat Jul  9 14:54:24 UTC 2022
starting script on Sat Jul  9 14:54:25 UTC 2022
starting script on Sat Jul  9 14:54:26 UTC 2022
starting script on Sat Jul  9 14:54:27 UTC 2022
starting script on Sat Jul  9 14:54:28 UTC 2022
starting script on Sat Jul  9 14:54:29 UTC 2022
starting script on Sat Jul  9 14:54:30 UTC 2022
starting script on Sat Jul  9 14:54:31 UTC 2022
starting script on Sat Jul  9 14:54:32 UTC 2022
starting script on Sat Jul  9 14:54:34 UTC 2022
starting script on Sat Jul  9 14:54:35 UTC 2022
```

Comment: Add `2>&1` to the end of the cron command, so you'll see error messages in the log.

Comment: If your script requires access to a GUI, it's not (trivially) runnable as a `cron` job.

Comment: Error messages should end up in your email inbox if `cron` is running on a system where email is available. Examine the system logs to see where it was sent.

Comment: See also [Why is testing “$?” to see if a command succeeded or not, an anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313216/why-is-testing-to-see-if-a-command-succeeded-or-not-an-anti-pattern)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CRON environment may be different; e.g., the `PATH` may be different and a `python` executable may not be in the CRON `PATH`.  Consider adding an `export PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin` or similar to your script prior to executing a first external command, a reasonable safety standard to consider anyway.  Alternatively, you could call all externals via their absolute path, though that can easily become cumbersome.

Reiterating Barmar, do consider redirecting `stderr` either to `stdout` or to a file to capture errors; e.g., `2>&1` (add stderr to stdout), `2> /tmp/manheim.err` (clobber and write stderr to file), or `2>> /tmp/manheim.err` (append stderr to file).

A few other/unrelated thoughts that may be worth considering, if you haven't already:

- Unless `mmr-gen.py` is monitoring and following its parent process, a `kill -9` to a `start-manheim.sh` process would kill `start-manheim.sh`, though not `mmr-gen.py`.
- Consider a mutual exclusion lock of some kind for preventing duplicative runs, as opposed to killing and restart previous script runs (e.g., a Bash `noclobber` lock).
- Consider running Bash scripts`errexit` enabled (`#!/bin/bash -e`, `set -e`, or `set -o errexit`).  `errexit` is helpful for exception safety and handling discipline.
- Consider using `[[ ]]`, as opposed to `[ ]`, assuming use Bash, Z Shell, or another supporting Bash variant.  `[[ ]]` is generally more efficient and syntactically forgiving.
- `-eq`, `-ne`, and the like are arithmetic operators, while `==`, `!=`, and the like are *technically* string operators (e.g., `[ 1 == 01 ]` does not evaluate to true, while `[ 1 -eq 01 ]` does).  In your case, the distinction shouldn't be relevant, though intention and consistency in scripting are generally good practices to consider.

Given the `echo` output, the script is clearly running; though, to tripleee's comment, and for completeness, the following are also good to check (lots drawn from the other post, which has a great deal of useful information):

- Check for errors reported by/through CRON (e.g., `find /var/log -maxdepth 1 -type f -mmin -60 -exec grep -Hi cron '{}' \; | less -S`).
- Verify how your CRON flavor handles `stdout` and `stderr` (e.g., `* * * * * echo stdout; echo stderr 1>&2` and check default or specific `MAILTO` [if there is one] and/or files [e.g., `find /var/{log,spool/mail} -maxdepth 1 -type f -mmin -60 -exec zegrep -H 'std(err|out)' '{}' \;`]).
- Check the inherited CRON environment (e.g., `* * * * * /usr/bin/env > /tmp/env`, examine `/tmp/env`, and remove the job).  Specifically, for example, check that the inherited `PATH` is sufficient.
- Verify that CRON is indeed running (e.g., `pgrep -P 1 -U root cron`) and, if not, investigate and, if safe to do so, (re)start it (e.g., `systemctl start cron.service`).  *Given the `echo` output, this isn't a problem here.*
- Verify that your command is executable by CRON (e.g., an appropriate execute bit [e.g., `chmod -v 0755 start-manheim.sh`, assuming the script is OK to be world readable and executable] and a correct shebang [e.g., `#!/bin/bash -e`]).  *Given the `echo` output, this isn't a problem here.*
- Review documentation for your flavor of CRON (e.g., `man 5 crontab`) for crontab syntax correctness and subtleties (e.g., presence of unescaped `%`s).

Comment: This is a good start, but very incomplete compared to the debugging tips in the duplicate question.

Comment: that's exactly what happened, my python script uses PATH and it couldn't find the required file that are supposed to be in path. 
thank you so much for you help